# How to bypass reCaptchaV2 with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, captcha

so i'm trying to bypass a recaptchaV2 with CapMonster but I don't think i'm using the right website key. So if anyone had an idea It would be great !

The website I'm trying to Bypass : https://www.sneakql.com/en-GB/launch/culturekings/womens-air-jordan-1-high-og-court-purple-au/register

I have succeeded to get the captcha request and the InnerHTML worked well but now I can't submit at all and I don't know why

I tried to follow this git project : https://gist.github.com/alperensert/ea02f8ec6129bc2289a8ad12d9a76e55

On the screenshot, I think this is the website key but I'm not sure
[image]
The code i'm trying to use :

```
            #website_key = "6LcEQb0UAAAAAFluVqTQqxfo1T9f7SM7jycCZBET"
            #website_url = chrome.current_url

            #captcha = NoCaptchaTaskProxyless(client_key="Capmonster API")
            #taskId = captcha.createTask(website_url, website_key)
            #response = captcha.joinTaskResult(taskId)
            #chrome.execute_script(f"document.getElementsByClassName('g-recaptcha-response')[0].innerHTML = '{response}';")
```

Comment: that iframe is not present on sign up page, Is that available only after login ?

Comment: That iframe is present at the last step, logged or not

Comment: Yes, that's the right key.